# Unsure about these operators being used in this way

Tags: c++

This code example comes from http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/templates/ :

```
template <class myType>
myType GetMax (myType a, myType b) {
 return (a>b?a:b);
}
```

What I am confused about is the "a>b?a:b" section part of the code which is being returned. Can somebody help me to understand what is going on here? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the ternary operator. It evaluates the expression before the `?`, and if it's true, the value before the `:` is returned. Otherwise, the value after the `:` is returned.

It is basically a concise way of expressing the following if/else statement:

```
if ( a>b)
{
    return a;
}
else
{
    return b;
}
```

Comment: I understand the part about checking to see if what is before the ternary operator is true, but why the a before the : ? <- (That's a regular question mark, btw!)

Comment: @angrytoad Because that's where you put the value to return if the expression is true.

Answer (score 1):

It's known as the ternary operator:

http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/1AUq5Di1/

You can think of `return (a > b) ? a : b;` as:

```
if(a>b) {
  return a;
} else {
  return b;
}
```

Keep in mind that the ternary operator actually produces a value, which is either a or b (which is why it works in the `return` statement).

So you can do things like

`myType c = (a>b) ? a : b`, which is roughly equivalent to

```
myType c;
if(a > b) {
  c = a;
} else {
  c = b;
}
```